# Understanding tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I read through the official tensorflow tutorial and it is bit hard to understand. All new elements, like device and session, seem to be introduced at random moments. Hence, I'm curious if there's a conceptual/global overview of tensorflow?

Comment: Have you read this page ? It's still technical, but general.    https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started

Comment: You should also look here: https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials

Comment: @gdelab Thank you very much, this is very helpful. Still some questions remain like what is `get_global_step` function what is parameter list? Is reading source code the only way to go?

Comment: Usually graph have a (more or less hidden) integer variable called `global_step`, that is meant to be just a counter of interesting iterations from the start. When you train a NN, an interesting iteration is usually a training step, so this variable should count the number of training steps in your gradient descent. `get_global_step` just gives you access to this variable. In this tutorial it's used to group it with the training step, so that this counter indeed gets incremented each time you perform a training step.

Comment: Usually the doc is enough to understand the purpose of a function (in python the doc is pretty complete), otherwise asking questions is probably more efficient than reading the code...

Comment: Have a look at https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/go/2017/05/29/understanding-tensorflow-using-go/ - it uses Go to explain, but the concepts remain valid

Comment: @gdelab Thank you again for clarifying. How did you learn about `get_global_step`?